# In what cases should I use UUID as primary key in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

What are advantages and disadvantages of UUID field?

When should I use it as a primary key? When should I use default primary key?

My table has many rows. Is it possible that max value of default primary key will be exceeded?

I use PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

**Primary Key -**

It is an auto-increment unique key which is created by database engine                   when we create a new record each time to the table.

**UUID  -**

It is unique too but it is unique in "*the whole universe*", not **guaranteed unique** but **practically unique**. Like when we want create a ticket based environment to solve customer issues then we must generate a ticket_id by UUID(because its unique and it is combination of random numbers).

If you want to go deep into it then check this awesome blog [here](https://medium.com/@Mareks_082/auto-increment-keys-vs-uuid-a74d81f7476a)